# ios what does a delegate default to

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, delegates

If you don't specify a delegate, is the `self` the default delegate?

Also, if you have a `UITextField` do you need to make sure it's knows it is a `UITextFieldDelegate` or is it one by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you don't specify a delegate,

Of what object? It is up to the implementation of the specific object to decide.

> is the self the default delegate?

No, in the absence of any other information, the delegate would probably be nil.

However, if you were writing a class implementation, and wanted the object to set its delegate to `self` by default, you could certainly do that. I think this would usually be more confusing than useful, though.

If you want to do something by default, just check if the delegate is nil. (Somebody could always set your delegate to be nil, so you have to do that check anyway.)

> If you have a UITextField do you need to make sure it knows it is a UITextFieldDelegate or is it one by default?

`UITextField` does not implement any of the methods in `UITextFieldDelegate` -- or at least it doesn't advertise that it does so -- so I'm not sure what you mean here. A `UITextField` by itself cannot function as a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

If you were to subclass `UITextField` and add methods in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, then you could mark it as implementing `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

But that doesn't happen by default, you have to make it happen.

Comment: ***"However, if you were writing a class implementation, and wanted the object to set its delegate to `self` by default, you could certainly do that."*** If by `self` you mean the instance of a class setting itself as its own delegate - sure. If you mean setting the instance from which this class is being instantiated as a delegate, as I think the OP meant (since the other case makes no sense) - not really. Same thing with `UITextField` - I think you misunderstood the OP.

Comment: Entirely possible, it's a confusing question. If the OP can clarify, please do.